# redirect with javascript without loading the master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

i have an asp.net application under c#

my application consists of master page and its children

in my master page i set a menu

i need when i click on an item in the menu, i need to call a javascript function to redirect to this page without load the master page again.

for example: i am in home page and i want to redirect to contact us page, when i click in the contact us link in the menu, i need to load only the part of the page  that not related to the master page.

i know that to load a part of the page i must use jquery, that's why i use jquery to send json request by a web service to a service and get info and represent these info in contact us page.

**Problem:**
how can redirect from one page to another without loading master page?

**Note:**
i try ispostback in master page page load method and windows.location = "contactus" in javascript method

any help?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: From what I gather he wants to load the content into the same page, not redirect, so when they click Contact Us he wants the Contact Us content to appear in the page using AJAX.

Comment: As Michal says, your question doesn't make sense - unless you are talking about changing the content of a page without actually doing an entire page post-pack - so you should look at using the AJAX facilities in ASP.NET 3.5+ (in particular the use of `<asp:UpdatePanel>`)  **Edit:** Although this will not allow you (without some clever code-behind processing) to bring in the contents of another client page that is based on that Master page)

Comment: The concept of master pages in ASP.NET doesn't allow that. You would need to implement your content pages without master page reference and then load them with ajax call.

Comment: You can do what you need using iframe but that brings some other issues.

Comment: i used jquery to get content to contact us page

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not "redirecting" the user, but rather loading content (via AJAX) with which you will replace a certain area of the page with.
Like you said, you'd do that with jQuery;

```
jQuery("#selectorToGetTheMainNode").load("http://urlToLoadTheHTMLFrom");
```

This will automatically load and replace the html present within your MainNode with the loaded content.